# express-validator returns validation errors twice

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, express-validator

I want to validate the request object using Express-Validator. Let's assume I have two routes, a *GET /users/:id* (fetchUserById) and *POST /users* (createUser) route

```
this.router = express.Router();
this.router.route('/').post(this.userRequestValidator.createUser, this.userController.createUser);
this.router.route('/:id').get(this.userRequestValidator.fetchUserById, this.userController.fetchUserById);
```

As you can see I call the validation middleware right before calling the controller logic. First I created a base validator dealing with the validation errors and returning a HTTP 400 if something failed.

```
export abstract class RequestValidator {
    protected validate = async (request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void> => {
        const errors: Result<ValidationError> = validationResult(request);

        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
        } else {
            next();
        }
    };
}
```

My validator functions *userRequestValidator.createUser* and *userRequestValidator.fetchUserById* just have to extend the RequestValidator and implement the validations

```
export class UserRequestValidator extends RequestValidator {
    public createUser = [
        body('username')
            .isString()
            .exists(),
        body('password')
            .isString()
            .exists(),
        this.validate,
    ];

    public fetchUserById = [
        param('id')
            .isString()
            .isUUID()
            .exists(),
        this.validate,
    ];
}
```

When I call `GET localhost:3000/users/abc` I get this response

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "value": "abc",
            "msg": "Invalid value",
            "param": "id",
            "location": "params"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the response I am expecting. But when I call `POST localhost:3000/users` with an empty body I get this response

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "msg": "Invalid value",
            "param": "username",
            "location": "body"
        },
        {
            "msg": "Invalid value",
            "param": "username",
            "location": "body"
        },
        {
            "msg": "Invalid value",
            "param": "password",
            "location": "body"
        },
        {
            "msg": "Invalid value",
            "param": "password",
            "location": "body"
        }
    ]
}
```

Does someone know how I can fix this behaviour or what's wrong with my setup?

Comment: which version of express-validator are you using?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't know why when `req.body` is a empty object - `{}`, the validator will run through all node of validation chain. You can check again, add each message for each condition, like as follow:

```
class UserRequestValidator extends RequestValidator {
  public createUser = [
    body('username')
      .isString().withMessage('username must be a string') // you can see both error messages in the response
      .exists().withMessage('username must be exist'),
    body('password') // the same for this field
      .isString()
      .exists(),
    this.validate,
  ];

  public fetchUserById = [
    param('id') // because id is exist in `req.params`, then only one test has been executed.
      .isString().withMessage('id must be a string')
      .isUUID()
      .exists(),
    this.validate,
  ];
}
```

I found a solution for your case in https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator/issues/638 , stop chain in the first error with `.bail()` function.

Then your validator class will be like:

```
class UserRequestValidator extends RequestValidator {
  public createUser = [
    body('username')
       // always check exists() first
      .exists().withMessage('username must be exist').bail()
      .isString().withMessage('username must be a string').bail(),
    body('password')
      .exists().bail()
      .isString().bail(),
    this.validate,
  ];

  public fetchUserById = [
    param('id')
      .isString()
      .isUUID()
      .exists(),
    this.validate,
  ];
}
```

Comment: sorry, I can reward the bounties in 11 hours

Answer (score 3):

You can also set `onlyFirstError` to `true` when retrieving the error array.
From the [documentation](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/validation-result-api.html#array-options):

> If the option onlyFirstError is set to true, then only the first error
> for each field will be included

Example usage:

```
function validateRequestParams (req, res, next) {
    const errors = validationResult(req)

    if (errors.isEmpty()) {
        return next()
    } else {
        return res.status(400).json({
            bodyValidationErrors: errors.array({ onlyFirstError: true })
        })
    }
}
```